# What is $d(\sin(x),\cos(x))$ if d is a distance function in a metric space?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M=\{f:[a,b] \to \textbf{R} | f \,is \,continuous \}$. Let $d:M \to \textbf{R}$ be defined by $d(f,g)=\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| \,dx$. What is d represent geometrically, and show that M, d is a metric space. What is $d(\sin(x),\cos(x))$ for $[a,b]=[0, 2\pi]$?

$\textbf{What does d represent geometrically?}$

d represents absolute value of the area of the region that is bounded by the functions f and g.

$\textbf{Show that M,d is a metric space.}$

$\textbf{Proof:}$ For M to be a metric space, it must satisfy the following properties:

- If $f,g \in M$ with $d(f,g)=0$, then $f=g$ (vice versa).

Let $f,g \in M$. Assume $d(f,g)=\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| \,dx=0$.
$$ \int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| \,dx=0 \iff |f(x)-g(x)|=0 \iff$$ \begin{cases} 
      f(x)-g(x)=0 \iff f(x)=g(x)\\
      -(f(x)-g(x))=0 \iff f(x)=g(x)\\
   \end{cases}
Hence $f=g$.

- If $f,g \in M$, then $d(f,g)=d(g,f)$.

Let $f,g \in M$. Assume $d(f,g)=\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| \,dx$.
$$d(f,g)=\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)| \,dx=\int_a^b |-(g(x)-f(x))| \,dx=\int_a^b |g(x)-f(x)| \,dx=d(g,f)$$
Hence $d(f,g)=d(g,f)$.

- Triangle Inequality

Let $f,g,h \in M$. Assume $d(f,h)=\int_a^b |f(x)-h(x)| \,dx$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
d(f,h) & =\int_a^b |f(x)-h(x)| \,dx \\
& =\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)+g(x)-h(x)| \,dx\\
& \leq \int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)-h(x)| \,dx\\
& =\int_a^b |f(x)-g(x)|\,dx + \int_a^b|g(x)-h(x)| \,dx\\
& =d(f,g)+d(g,h) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Hence $d(f,h) \leq d(f,g)+d(g,h)$.

Hence M,d is a metric space.

$\textbf{What is $d(\sin(x),\cos(x))$ for $[a,b]=[0, 2\pi]$?}$

$$d(\sin(x),\cos(x))=\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(x)-\cos(x)| \,dx=(-\cos(x)-\sin(x))]_0^{2 \pi}=0$$
**Is this correct?**

Correction: \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
d(\sin(x),\cos(x)) & =\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(x)-\cos(x)| \,dx \\
& =\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \cos(x)-sin(x)\,dx +\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{5\pi}{4} \sin(x)-cos(x)\,dx+\int_\frac{5\pi}{4}^{2\pi} \cos(x)-sin(x)\,dx \\
& = \sqrt{2}-1+2\sqrt{2}+1+\sqrt{2}\\
& =4\sqrt{2} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Sanity check: $d(f,g)=0$ if and only if $f=g$. (Do you see why?) The issue in your last line is that you ignored the absolute value sign.

Comment: You said yourself that $d(f,g)$ represents the absolute value of the area - what you've computed is the _signed_ area between the functions.  A big hint for evaluating the integral with the AV: on what regions is $\sin(x)\gt\cos(x)$, and on what regions is it the other way around?  Looking at the graphs should help here.

Answer (score 1):

You claim that if the integral of $|f-g|$ is zero, then $f - g$ must be zero, but without any supporting argument. Consider the function $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ except $f(0) = 1$, while $g(x) = 0$. The integral of the absolute value of the difference of these over the interval $[-1, 1]$ is zero, but the function difference is certainly not zero.

Your claim is actually true, but requires proof...including a reason that will outlaw the case I just proposed as a "counterexample".

Your integral  at the bottom is wrong, however. The function and its absolute value are different, and you need to address that by breaking the integral into multiple parts. (It also contradicts what you supposedly proved above: that if $d(f, g) = 0$, then $f = g$!)

Comment: He is working with continuous functions. And a continuous positive function has integral $0$ iff it is $0$.

Comment: I knew that. I wanted *him* to realize that continuity was an essential requirement for the proof to be valid. I guess he probably does realize that now. :(

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot simply drop the absolute values.
You have to break up the integral into pieces where $\sin x > \cos x$ and vice versa. The answer should be $4\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Also $\sin$ and $\cos$ are indeed different functions and you just proved that if your answer was zero then they are the same.

Comment: How would I calculate this interval? Hence when will $\sin(x)-\cos(x)$ be negative in this interval?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown See Steven's comment on your original question. You have to look at the graphs of $\sin$ and $\cos$ and handle the two cases $\sin(x)>\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x) < \cos(x)$ separately.

Comment: \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
d(\sin(x),\cos(x)) & =\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin(x)-\cos(x)| \,dx \\
& =\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \cos(x)-sin(x)\,dx +\int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{5\pi}{4} \sin(x)-cos(x)\,dx+\int_\frac{5\pi}{4}^{2\pi} \cos(x)-sin(x)\,dx \\
& = \sqrt{2}-1+2\sqrt{2}+1+\sqrt{2}\\
& =4\sqrt{2} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}